# How to square an array's elements while using a "while" loop without using "inject", "each", "collect" or "map" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing some pre-course work for Bootcamp and am having trouble with this problem.

I need to square an array while using a `while` loop and nothing else. `numbers = [1,2,3]` and it needs to equal `[1,4,9]`:

```
def square_array(numbers)
  counter = 0
  while numbers[counter] do
    return numbers[counter]
    counter += 1
  end
  counter ** 2
end
```

Comment: `while numbers[counter]` Ask yourself what would bring that to an end. `counter ** 2` It is not `counter` that needs to be squared, it's whatever is at the appropriate spot in `numbers`; think about how you would access that based on `counter`.

Comment: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)"

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". We're not interested in your programming level, we do care about the effort put into solving the question prior to asking, and how well you asked.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Without using array-map:

```
def square_array(numbers)
  counter = 0
  sqr_numbers=[]
  while numbers[counter] do
    sqr_numbers<<numbers[counter]*numbers[counter]
    counter += 1
  end
  sqr_numbers
end
```

You can [`map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map) each element of the array and square it or do whatever you want:

```
def square_array(numbers)
  return numbers.map {|num| num ** 2}
end
```

Comment: I believe the point of the question is that `map` is forbidden. Also please don't solve people's homework for them.

Comment: I miss that one. my bad

Comment: Well the title “cant use inject, each, collect or map“ is pretty good clue.

Comment: Fernand, knowing that you have answered a question that wasn't asked you should change our delete your answer. You could help the OP get on track without giving a complete answer. You could explain, for example, the problem with `...while numbers[counter]...`.

Comment: Please don't use "edited" or "updated" tags when changing your answer (or questions). We can see what's changed if we need to. Instead, incorporate the change into the text as if it'd been there initially. Clarity and readability is more important than showing the chain of edits.

Comment: @theTinMan, and I get a downvote for that? I didn't see in the rules I am not allowed to use those keywords. And I put those keywords because I thought it was more readable. tsk.

Comment: It appears you didn't answer the OPs question, got called on it, then edited your question poorly to update it. I edited it to bring the content in line with the recommendations for the site. That's how SO works.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading the link in my comment to the question. Homework, whether it's from a school or a self-assigned learning exercise, needs to be handled differently from a regular question as the goal to homework is to figure it out by ourselves; It's to help learn problems solving and self-reliance. We don't help if we toss out a fish, but if we help them learn to fish....

Comment: @theTinMan, Your link still doesn't answer the question, I did not ridicule OP's questions and I answered in good faith. The downvote is when the answer is not useful. But your way of downvote is to discourage people to answer. You could just have pointed out that there is a better format... "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines (unless the answer would merit downvotes even if the question weren't homework related)."